# Http block in nginx config breaks my server configuration

Tags: nginx

I was trying to organize my nginx config file a little better by adding an `http` block.

This is the working config file.

```
upstream node_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    index index.html;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://node_server;
    }
}
```

However when I wrap this code in a `http` block it breaks. i.e.

```
http{

    upstream node_server {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000 fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        index index.html;
        server_name _;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_pass http://node_server;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this might be the case. To my knowledge you can wrap server blocks inside the http block.

Comment: Is there an error message? Is this file called `nginx.conf` or is it included into another file which already wraps it within an `http` block?

Comment: OK, so that was the issue. This file was being included inside another files `http` block.